# Adding column to dataframe with sum from date range

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I have two dataframes with information about accounts. One with strategies (df) and one with transactions (df2). I need another column in the transaction-dataframe with which strategy every account has at the transaction-date.

I am thinking of two solutions, both using df.apply and lambda functions, taking input date and account from transactions and returning strategy. Both generates errors. I am now looking for any way to move forward.Thanks.

```
import pandas as pd


strategy_data = [['001', '2018-03-02', '2018-03-04', 'strat1'],['001', '2018-03-05', '2018-03-10', 'strat2'],['002', '2018-02-01', '2018-03-02', 'strat2']]
df = pd.DataFrame(strategy_data, columns = ['acc', 'd1', 'd2', 'strat'])

transaction_data = [['001', '2018-03-02', 234], ['001', '2018-03-03', 432], ['001', '2018-03-07', 543], ['002', '2018-02-20', 543]]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(transaction_data, columns = ['acc', 'd', 'am'])
```

Idea 1

```
def return_strat(acc, date):
    df3 = df.loc(lambda df: df['acc'] == acc)
    df3 = df3.loc(lambda df3: df3['d1'] < date)
    df3 = df3.loc(lambda df3: df3['d2'] > date)
    return df3['strat'].value

df2['strat'] = df2.apply(lambda row : return_strat(row['acc'], row['d']), index=1)
```

Idea 2

```
df2['strat'] = df2.apply(lambda row : df.loc((df.acc == row['acc']) & ( df.d1 <= row['d'] <= df.d2)), axis=1)
```

Expected output is a new column in df2 with current strategy per transaction.

Option 1 generates ValueError: ("No axis named . at 0x11ac976a8> for object type ", 'occurred at index 0')

Option 2 generates ValueError: ('The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().', 'occurred at index 0')

Answer (score 0):

Try using .applymap instead of .apply when you use a lambda function that takes in more than 1 column